# I can't remove the timestamp from my column header

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column header in the XLSM file with dates like 20221031, 20221101, 20221102, ...
After I read the file in Python, I got this instead, 2022-10-31 00:00:00, 2022-11-01 00:00:00 ...

I tried to remove the timestamp by using the below codes, but it did not help.

```
selected_columns = df.columns[2:]

for column in df.columns:
    if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[column]):
        df[column] = df[column].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

How can I remove the timestamp from the third column onwards?

Thank you.

Comment: That's just python interpreting date objects without times as midnight. Don't worry about it

Comment: You are confusing the CONTENT of the data with the PRESENTATION of the data.  The timestamps do not actually contain a time, but times are stored to the second.  Just set the output format when you display the data.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[column]):
        df[column] = df[column].dt.date()
```